# How to check/validate avaliblity of .so or exe in Userspace from Kernel space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a userspace exe and corresponding changes in the kernel. I would like to have a check in kernel code regarding userspace exe status(available/ deleted).

Comment: I can make use of char dev from Userspace tO K-Space. but I dont want to add another dev file. I'm searching for diff ways to achieve this.

Comment: You are really approaching this backwards form a design perspective.  The kernel should not depend on userspace, rather, userspace should attempt to *enable* kernel functionality and connect to it through a recognized means, or possibly load a kernel module (if available) if the kernel part of the capability is not already present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to open it by function *filp_open* in the kernel, if you just want to know whether that file exist or not.